# if statement saying it's false even though it's true. Equals not working

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

The problem is that the variables "check" and "password" are both the same string, but the if statement says it's false for some reason. How do i fix this exactly?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Manager {
   public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static boolean isPasswordSet;
   public static String password;
   public static void password() {
    String check;
    while (true) {
        if (isPasswordSet == false) {
            System.out.println("Please set a new password: ");
            password = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter password again: ");
            check = input.next();
            if (check == password) {
                isPasswordSet = true;
                System.out.println("Welcome");
                return;
            } else if (check != password) {
                System.out.println("Password incorrect.");
                isPasswordSet = false;
                continue;
            }
        } else if (isPasswordSet == true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter password: ");
            check = input.next();
            if (check == password) {
                System.out.println("Welcome");
            } else if (check != password) {
                System.out.println("Password incorrect.");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    password();
}
```

}

Output:

```
Please set a new password: 
ryan
Enter password again: 
ryan
Password incorrect.
Please set a new password:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java

Comment: You might also want to checkout codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @simonv, codereview isn't a debugging service.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - I know, but that code really needs a review after this issue is fixed.